# azure devops extension storage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Is there a way to connect directly to the azure devops storage? there is an API for retrieving all the documents or it can be done by a name, but there is no possibility to  filter..so it means, each time api is called, all the documents are returned.

[https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{company}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/.../Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/.../Documents](https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/%7Bcompany%7D/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/.../Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/.../Documents)

here is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage?view=azure-devops#data-collections-of-documents-storage

i was wondering where all thes "documents" are stored? maybe in sql server that could be accessed from outside?

Comment: What documents are you looking for? If you are looking for pipeline related data such as logs and so on they are stored in the build machine's FS.

Comment: installed extensions can store data as settings or as json documents. those documents are returned as json objects via rest APi, but it does now have any filtering.

Answer (score 0):

We use this url to store data from the outside and read it from a custom extension:

```
PUT https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisher}/{extension}/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{document}/Documents?api-version=3.1-preview.1
Authorization: Basic :<PAT>
Content-Type: application/json

{
    ...data
    "id": "glencore",
    "__etag": 0
}
```

the `__etag` is used for optimistic concurrency.